# Sul significato di 'progetto retrospettivo'

Tags: meaning

> La mostra alla Fondazione Galleria Civica di Trento è parte di un più ampio *progetto retrospettivo* che include le mostre tenutesi, nel 2010, presso Villa Arson, Centre national d’art contemporain di Nizza e Salzburger Kunstverein di Salisburgo.

Se non erro, o, come dicono certi, non vado errato, un progetto è qualcosa che si riferisce al futuro e, per contro, retrospettiva è una cosa che si riferisce al passato.

Se così, cosa significa precisamente 'progetto retrospettivo' lì sopra?

Comment: La risposta che nessuno può darti: spesso e volentieri le persone usano parole (che normalmente avrebbero un significato preciso) in modo poco sensato, solo per fare scena. "Progetto retrospettivo", qualunque cosa significhi, è una gran figata, "come fosse Antani". O se preferisci, "la tua richiesta esprime cogenza in un sublimarsi d'oblio"!

Comment: Giusto, @gd1, e in effetti per qualche motivo questo tende a succedere più spesso proprio nel linguaggio dei critici d'arte e dei cataloghi. (Ho amici traduttori anglofoni che si strappano i capelli quando devono tradurre testi di questo tipo dall'italiano...)

Answer (score 7):

Direi che “retrospettivo” qui non sia nel senso generale di “rivolto all'indietro”, ma mutui il significato da quello della forma sostantivata “[retrospettiva](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/retrospettiva/)”, nel senso di mostra con un ampio respiro storico. Quindi un “progetto retrospettivo” sarà un programma composto da varie mostre di questo tipo collegate.

Però è vero, alla lettera è un bell'ossimoro.

Comment: Come mai il voto negativo, tanto per capire dove ho sbagliato?

Answer (score 3):

Potrebbe anche darsi che si intenda un insieme futuro (da cui il "progetto") di rievocazioni del passato (da cui "retrospettivo").